# Copying files after the msbuild do copy to the root folder $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, msbuild-task

I want to copy some of the files from the $(Build.SourcesDirectory) to the final package in azure deployment but after the msbuild it creates a name.zip folder and rest of the files are included outside of the zip.
Is there a way to include files along with the zip folder. I want the files inside the zip folder + the outside files

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
          inputs:
            restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

        - task: VSBuild@1
          inputs:
            solution: '$(solution)'
            msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
            platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
            configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

        - task: CopyFiles@2
          displayName: 'Copy files'
          inputs:
            SourceFolder: 'folder/folder1/'
            Contents: '**'
            targetFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            OverWrite: true
            CleanTargetFolder: false

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
          inputs:
            ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
            appType: 'webApp'
            azureSubscription: 'subscription1'
            WebAppName: 'testapp'
            packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/*.zip'
            RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: false
            enableCustomDeployment: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the files inside the zip folder + the outside files

To meet your requirement, you can  extract the zip file first and then copy the required files to the corresponding folder, and finally generate a new zip file.

You can use [Extract files Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops) to extract the zip file and [Archive files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) to generate a new zip file.

Here is an example:

```
steps:

xxx

- task: ExtractFiles@1
  displayName: 'Extract files '
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip'
    destinationFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/test'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/test'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: folder/folder1/
    TargetFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/test'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/test'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/test'

xx
```

Comment: Thank you, the above helped me after doing a bit more tasks. but thank you!